# Legacy system content import tool

Tags: interface, users, wizard, system

We have an old system, which is a course platform, and we are developing a new version of it, with other technology and some new features.

I am designing the feature that will allow users to migrate content from the old to the new version of the system.

We have already defined that this import can be optional, that is, if he wants to continue using the old platform yet, he can. But I'm in doubt about the friendliest way to offer this to users.

I imagine that working on a concept and wizards is interesting, where each step corresponds to a block of information to be imported, for example:

1. Import the courses
2. Import modules and classes
3. Import students
4. Notices and conclusion

At each step, he could select what he wants to import and what he wants to delete, and thus perform the task.

The question is: is this a friendly way of working? is there a model that can be more efficient to reduce friction in this task?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution to UXSE. As the question stands, there isn't really enough detail to provide an answer which is not going to be based on personal opinions/experiences and assumptions, which we discourage on this forum. It is best to solve UX problems by understanding the full context and be able to provide solutions that address the specific needs of the project and users. If you can update the questions with more details, mockups, screenshots and any other information that will help that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm also fairly new around here.

Your question is a bit broad one. It heavily depends on three factors 
- Technology Details
- Userbase
- Company's time and investment on this process.

In a most Google-y way, whole process can be done with a single button click and it could be done on the background for your users but I get that there's no such technology involved with the project.

Letting your users handle the migration is a one way to approach but there goes the technical factors. Are users previous users or are you trying to get leads from competitors? Are the data been stored on JSON files or are they some special format specific to the regional educational technology standards.

So as you can see there's lots of stuff that you need to clarify so we can also give you specific answers.

Oh, forgot to answer your question. As a user (and I believe most of the users are the same) I love one click import tools where I don't do anything at all. Doing work for the tools are boring and not user-friendly at all -unless they're paying to that task. For example, I recently imported my 1Password registries to Bitwarden. There was a very simple guide on Bitwarden explaining how to export my registries from 1Password. After exporting I just selected the exported file from Bitwarden and my whole process was done within 4 clicks. That's how an import function work. Export file, select import, select file, click start import. Hope this would answer your question.

Love to hear more about the project if you'd like to talk more in detail.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your contribution to UXSE. Good attitude and approach to the question based on the information provided, and hopefully there will be an update so you can provide a more specific answer :)

Comment: Yeah would love to hear more sounds like an interesting challenge.

I've recently decided to get my hands dirty with development starting with JS. The thing is, I think I've dipped my whole arms into mud instead just my hands lol. I had a question in stack overflow and noticed UXSE and immediately joined. I've been working as a professional designer nearly a decade so I hope I can also contribute with my knowledge here meanwhile asking very ultra beginner questions on Stackoverflow  Thanks for your kind words, see you around.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and comment. I updated the text with more information, I hope I managed to make it clearer to get more answers!